# Vue js, cannot read property $el

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have the problem with correctly understood the flow elements, method calling in vue js. It is the standard idea - fetching some data from rest api, and render it on the browser.

The getting method I wrote into `mounted()`. Also I added there calling `renderHomePageMethod()`. This method was written in `methods:`

```
 mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/test").then(response => {
      this.testData= response.data
      this.renderHomePageMethod();
    });
  }
```

In `renderHomePageMethod()` I used `this.refs$` and `$el`. And probably there is the problem, everything is working fine, but in the browser I got warning about:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined
```

Probably I should calling

```
this.renderHomePageMethod()
```

in another place. But where?

Comment: can you try buffering like `var that = this;` and using `that` inside the response callback?

Comment: `mounted() {
    var that = this;
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/test").then(response => {
      this.testData= response.data
      that.renderHomePageMethod();
    });
  }`
That same error.

Comment: can you post your `renderHomePageMethod()`? Or if you can't, can you write `if(!this.$el) return;` at the first line of that method?

Comment: Thank you for your help. After added at the first line, error that same. The method is:
` renderHomePageMethod() {
    
      const width= this.$refs.compTest.$el.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = (window.innerWidth - width) / 5;
      this.$refs.svg.zoom.transform.x = x;

    }`

Comment: Ok, your referenced component is not ready when the component is mounted. Try emitting an event when the referenced component has been mounted, then run the renderHomePageMethod inside that event handler.

Comment: Hmm uff it is hard I think. Sorry for that, but can You send me any doc link etc., which will be helped for me?

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your referenced component is not rendered before the main component renders, so it gives a reference error.

A hackish way would be something like this:

```
mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/test").then(response => {
        this.testData= response.data
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.renderHomePageMethod();
        }, 1000); // or any other minimum delay before the subcomponent is rendered
    });
}
```

or the better and harder way, create an `event-bus.js` file which contains:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

in your main and sub components:

```
import { EventBus } from "./event-bus.js";
```

in your sub component, this will send the notification to the main component when it's ready to roll:

```
mounted(){
    EventBus.$emit("subcomponent:is-mounted");
}
```

in your main component:

```
data(){
    return {
       testData: null
    }
},
mounted(){
   axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/test").then(response => {
       this.testData= response.data
   });
   EventBus.$on("subcomponent:is-mounted", () =>{
       this.renderHomePageMethod();
   });
},
beforeDestroy(){
   EventBus.$off("subcomponent:is-mounted");
   // don't forget to remove the listeners because of duplicate listeners may occur 
   // if your component refreshes (remounts)
}
```